# Stale Data in after_commit after multiple updates to the same ActiveRecord object in a transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

**EDIT**: Updated the code snippet a little, to better reflect how I am saving the values.

I have a couple of nested transactions, and an object's `after_commit` hook is being triggered with not-the-most-recent state of the object when the transactions are committed.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord; end
class B < ApplicationRecord
  # I wanted to tell another service that this object has changed, but when I commit changes
  # i.e. I don't want to hear about .save inside a transaction that gets rolled back later on
  after_commit { broadcast(self) }
end

# b1 and b2 are existing instances of B

A.transaction do
  A.transaction do
    b1.val = 5
    b1.changed? && b1.save # it's possible that val was already 5
  end

  A.transaction do
    b1.val = 10
    b1.changed? && b1.save

    b2.val = 20
    b2.changed? && b2.save
  end
end
```

At the end of all of this, when the transaction is committed, I see two calls to `broadcast` (one for each instance of B, which makes sense), but the `b1` call is made with `val = 5`, not 10; even though the database has the correct values for both (10 for `b1` and 20 for `b2`).

This is all using Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.5.

Comment: When are you calling ``.save``? Replicating your example -- but using ``.update!`` in place of assignment -- I get your expected results with both Rails 6.0 and Rails 5.2.4.3. One call to ``.broadcast`` for each instance with the 'final' values.

Comment: @rmlockerd I've been calling it inside the inner transactions, after the value assignment - `b1.changed? && b1.save` (and the same way for `b2`). I'll explore using `.update!` and see how that works for me.

Comment: BTW, ``.changed`` returns an array of the changed attributes (or an empty array), so the way you are using it it will always be ``true``. I think you mean ``.changed?``, which is the dirty flag.

Comment: @rmlockerd, right, my bad; I am actually using `.changed?`, I just updated the post poorly.

Comment: Hmm, replacing the assignments with `.update!` actually led to even less desirable behaviors. Not only did the number of broadcasts jump (because I am not doing it even when the object hasn't changed), but the `b1` broadcast is still wrong, *and* the `b2` one broke as well. I guess there is something else going on that I don't think is relevant but must be...

Comment: I shouldn't have sidetracked you with ``.update``. I prefer it to set/save when just changing values, but when you mentioned that you are checking dirty flags, ``.update`` isn't useful.

Comment: Sorry, mate, I can't reproduce the problem with just your example. I get one broadcast for ``b2.val`` of 20 (if starting value isn't 20), and I always get a broadcast for ``b1.val`` of 10 even if starting value is 10. That makes sense because the database does change twice in that case (10 -> 5, then 5 -> 10) within the single transaction, but ``after_commit`` only receives the last (current) value in my tests.

Comment: @rmlockerd, it's okay, there must be something else going on. I tried to reproduce this with a couple of simple models and without all the fluff I am not showing in this example, and it was working fine for me too; there must be something I don't think is important but actually is. For now I am changing the `after_commit` hook to `after_save`. It leads to some extra broadcasts, but ultimately appears to work.